# lazyloader does not works on AOT production mode angular-cli

Tags: angular2-routing, angular-cli, lazy-loading

I am using angular-cli and lazyloader for routing.

`ng serve` works for me, but after building project as Production mode, then it does not work at all.

Here is my app.routing.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './core/guards/index';
//Layouts
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './main/main.module#MainModule'
      }
    ],
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },{
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'login'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

And this is error I got after `ng build --prod --aot` or `ng serve --prod`.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module './app/main/main.module'.
Error: Cannot find module './app/main/main.module'.
    at t (main.1f6da18….bundle.js:1)
    at t.loadAndCompile (vendor.490f84a….bundle.js:379)
    at t.load (vendor.490f84a….bundle.js:379)
    at t.loadModuleFactory (vendor.490f84a….bundle.js:428)
    at t.load (vendor.490f84a….bundle.js:428)
    at e.project (vendor.490f84a….bundle.js:428)
    at e.XO5T.e._tryNext (vendor.490f84a….bundle.js:897)
    at e.XO5T.e._next (vendor.490f84a….bundle.js:897)
    at e.next (vendor.490f84a….bundle.js:897)
    at e.RRVv.e._subscribe (vendor.490f84a….bundle.js:736)
    at t (main.1f6da18….bundle.js:1)
    at t.loadAndCompile (vendor.490f84a….bundle.js:379)
    at t.load (vendor.490f84a….bundle.js:379)
    at t.loadModuleFactory (vendor.490f84a….bundle.js:428)
    at t.load (vendor.490f84a….bundle.js:428)
    at e.project (vendor.490f84a….bundle.js:428)
    at e.XO5T.e._tryNext (vendor.490f84a….bundle.js:897)
    at e.XO5T.e._next (vendor.490f84a….bundle.js:897)
    at e.next (vendor.490f84a….bundle.js:897)
    at e.RRVv.e._subscribe (vendor.490f84a….bundle.js:736)
    at u (polyfills.1e19b2c….bundle.js:43)
    at u (polyfills.1e19b2c….bundle.js:43)
    at polyfills.1e19b2c….bundle.js:43
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.1e19b2c….bundle.js:36)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.490f84a….bundle.js:365)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.1e19b2c….bundle.js:36)
    at r.runTask (polyfills.1e19b2c….bundle.js:36)
    at o (polyfills.1e19b2c….bundle.js:36)
```

Here is screenshot of browser console.

[image]

What is wrong on my routing configuration? PP : `ng serve` is working with out any errors.

Comment: what happens when you run ng build --prod --aot false

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried that and test on apache server. it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`. Maybe there is some issue on my code?

Comment: There was a issue on my code. `loadChildren: './main/main.module.ts#MainModule'` I changed this as `loadChildren: './main/main.module#MainModule'`. And `ng build --prod --aot false` works well. What 's wrong with AoT?

Comment: Sorry, just checked again and `ng build --prod --aot false` does not works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is coming from `angular2-busy` module.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-busy

Removing this from project solved issue.

Comment: Thank you! After countless hours messing around with different versions of angular and angular cli, this turned out to be the culprit.

The real issue is that you won't notice this problem while developing, or even when building for production. No, this error pops up after you deploy when you try to use your application. And then you don't even get a clear error as to what the cause is. Simply astounding.